# A specific folder has all its files disappearing

Tags: directory, data-loss

I have a folder that I use pretty often that suddenly went empty and I've no clue why. I opened it one day and everything was gone. I had a fair bit of work in it, mostly video files for future projects I've got planned in my free time, so I was upset that I'd have to start from scratch. Thing is, everything I put in there now disappears as well like it's some kind of black hole folder.

I'd looked around for some kind of solution but the problem seems kind of unique and what very little I  find aren't Ubuntu-specific, mostly Windows, and gives me no help. I doubt if it's of any consequence, but this folder is in an external hard drive. Any advice?

I'll be honest, I'm not as tech savvy as I'd like to say I am, so my apologies if this is an easy fix that should have been obvious to me.

Comment: Where is the folder mounted? And please provide information on what you are doing.

Comment: Is it in `/tmp`?

Comment: If it is in /tmp like Arronical says,  just mount it to /home/yourusername/yourfolder

Comment: What is the location of that folder?